# Invalid Hook for react-router-dom call after following tutorial

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I recently watched the tutorial at https://youtu.be/Law7wfdg_ls and created a web app that mimics it exactly. I was trying to use BrowserRouter to navigate to a new page using Links. While his works, mine is giving me "invalid hook call" can anyone help me understand why this is happening? I have attached pictures of my App.js where I call the hooks and pictures of the error message.

[This is my code in App.js. The only difference from the tutorial are my page names and the use of 'Routes' rather than switch as routes replaced switch, and 'element' instead of component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jwr8N.png)

[This is the error message I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaUrp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you linked is from 2019, certainly it is not using the current version of `react-router-dom`!

The current version is v6.x, came with quite a few breaking changes.

To specifically address the issue you've asked about, one of the changes was to the `Route` components. They no longer use a `component,` render`, or` children`functions to render routed components, but instead use the singular`element`prop that takes a JSX literal, or rather, a`ReactElement`, value.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
  <Route path="/private" element={<Private />} />
  <Route path="/public" element={<Public />} />
</Routes>
```

I suggest following the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) to catch up on the rest of the changes from the v4/5 syntax you'll see in a lot of older RRD demos and tutorials.